# Linking subform on multiple keys

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a form and need to link a subform on a bit more than the primary key.  Sounds vague but bear with me please while I lay out a simplified version.

Imagine two tables.
Main table: AppealsLog with the fields AppealNum and AppealGroupNum as keys along with a good number of other information.  AppealNum is a unique identifier for each record.  AppealGroupNum uses AppealNum to link a group of records together.  For example, AppealNum 001, 002, 003, 004, and 005 can be assigned the AppealGroupNum of 001 so that all five records can be linked together in reports.
Child table:  AppealNotes with the fields AppealNum and AppealGroupNum as keys just like the main table.  Two additional fields called Comments (character field 255 long) and AppealGroupNote (logical field).

Now for the form.  The form will have all the fields from the main table.  There will also be a subform where I want to display any notes for that AppealNum along with any notes for the AppealGroupNum when AppealGroupNote is true.

I can link the two tables easily enough using AppealNum but cannot figure out how to also show the notes that have the correct AppealGroupNum and are marked as AppealGroupNote.  Any ideas to make this happen?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't really need to save AppealGroupNum into AppealNotes. Group identifier can be retrieved in query linking on AppealNum, assuming AppealNum is unique in AppealsLog. If AppealNum is repeated for a unique pair, that is different. Could use autonumber in AppealsLog as the key to link with AppealNotes.

Comment: Maybe structure should be modified to have a parent table for AppealGroups and this is where AppealGroupNote would reside. Isn't there other general info about groups that should be maintained?

Comment: Built-in subform binding is designed to work with *well-normalized* tables using primary and foreign keys. Change June7's "maybe" to "definitely" update table structure to be properly normalized for groups to make this easier. Otherwise, probably the only way to have a subform with specialized grouping and note-flag would be to unbind the subform (clear LinkMasterFields and LinkChildFields properties) and programmatically update the subform's RecordSource during the main form's `Form_Current()` event handler.

Comment: Although I just hinted at a possible solution for the subform, you're going to have nightmares as you try to develop other reports and queries for your groups, always having to program exceptions, etc.  You should reverse your design... instead of trying to place all notes in one table (AppealNotes) and then separating them in the form/subform using special flag columns, do the reverse by having a separate AppealGroup table (and possibly AppealGroupNotes table), then bring the data back together at the form or report level.  Display group notes in a separate subform from individual notes.

Comment: Sorry for going on, but the title implies that this is simply a matter of "multiple keys". Multiple keys are actually easily supported by separating key column names by semicolons in the subform's LinkMasterFields and LinkChildFields properties.  The real problem here is that there are *multiple* **conditions**, one for linking matches *only on AppealNum* and another for matching on AppealNum+AppealGroupNum where (AppealGroupNotes=True).  That sort of convoluted set of conditions is not supported with built-in binding.  It is important to understand the fundamental problem, hence this comment.